# Unable to call external javascript in aspx page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am a newbie to jquery. Help me out to solve this thing

I have this script in a separate js file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#btn_click").click(function () {
    $("#SecondLine").hide();
});
});
```

I want to execute this script in a click on the element with id="btn_click"

```
<form id="form1">
<div>
    <h2>This is a heading</h2>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p id="SecondLine">This is another paragraph.</p>       
    <p1 id="btn_click">Click me</p1>
</div>
</form>
```

The code works perfectly when i include the whole script between the head tag on the same aspx page. but it is not working when i have this code in a separate js file.
Note: I have included the script in aspx page.

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../JQuery/JQuery_HidingText.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Still not working :( .Did i Missed anything ?

Comment: Include only one version of jquery (full or min); check the console, do you see any error? Check your network console too (eg 404 errors).

Comment: yes Dani. I have just dragged and dropped the script file. So path will not be a problem i guess.

Comment: on firefox what does cntrl + shift + J reveal

Comment: @Bharath You don't need to include both jquery and jquery.min. That would cause a conflict. Jquery min is basically a minified version of jquery.

Comment: I have included only one version of jquery. No errors. But still script is not working.

Comment: I am getting this when i press ctrl+shift+j: \nTimestamp: 06/28/2013 4:54:21 PM
Warning: Expected identifier for pseudo-class or pseudo-element but found '['.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.
Source File: chrome://browser/skin/devtools/common.css
Line: 77

Comment: @Edward Can you pls tell me how and where to check for console errors?

Comment: Take a deep look here: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console#errors_and_warnings and https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network

Comment: @Edward I don't find anyother warnings or errors in console other than the above one.

Comment: @bharat if you know about firebug check if is external js file is loading in browser ....

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for the firebug tip man. External js file gets loaded in the browser.

Comment: @Bharath Try one thing take asp:button instead of p1 and also make a function in which you will hide your SecondLine element and call that function from that button ....

Comment: @Bharath put this as your external file see if alert box is coming

$(document).ready(function () {
alert('Testing');
});

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for your valuable suggestions Rahul. I have learned about firebug from you ;). Crab found the mistake that i had done in my code.Thats the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
pageLoad()
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
  //.. etc
});
```

The pageLoad uses a different method (timeouts) to check whether the DOM is ready. I had a script that failed with `$(document).ready` but worked with `pageLoad` - pageLoad hitting a fraction later which made the difference. This was only an issue in IE for me

Anyway might not work but easy to try and worth a go i reckon

See [here](http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/) for details pageLoad

And of course good luck

**Another thought**

Change the location of the external script file reference to just before the closing body tag rather than in the head. Again to give the markup the best chance of loading before the script executes (i know the document ready should do this but ...). Again worth a go

**And**

Just for test purpose i would change the external script file to be as simple as possible just to rule any other wierdness out i.e. use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('Hello - i am here');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Crab. I tried your suggestion. i have included this in script in pageLoad().Not working.

Comment: Also <p1 id="btn_click">Click me</p1> - is p1 tags a typo? Should they be p tags? Aplogies if someone has already picked this up

Comment: I was trying so many things from morning, searching blogs,asking my seniors help, sacrificing chickens to pagan gods :D.Nothing worked.I am really sorry guys. As Crab said, It should be p tags and Not P1. Now it is working. Sorry if i wasted your time for just this stupid typing error.

Answer (score 0):

You're load jQuery scripy twice.

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Remove one of them.

You should remove this file too:

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

After that check paths to scripts. Your script work [correctly](http://jsfiddle.net/CsSz4/).

Comment: Post this as a comment rather than answer. It does not answer problem

Comment: @YD1m I removed the min version. Nothing gets turned up :(

Comment: I only have this line - <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Use ~ symbol instead ..

~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"  instead of ../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"
~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" instead of ../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"

All the Best

Comment: @shanmugam: It does not make any sense to use ~ as OT is saying that he is dragging file for path....